# enabling remote desktop with command prompt

Tags: remote-desktop

can you give me a way for enabling my remote desktop with cmd ? 
my remote desktop port is not listening on 3389 !
my server : windows 2003

Answer (score 4):

To enable RDP via command line, just edit the registry with the reg command like this:

reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f

Comment: This will only work if the 'Terminal Services'  service is started

Comment: True, but it is always started by default. If somebody disabled it, run reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TermService /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000003 /f and then a net start termservice

Answer (score 2):

If you mean remotely, which isn't clear from your question. If you don't, omit step 2 and 3

1. Open Regedit on a Windows workstation
2. Click **File > Connect Network Registry**
3. Enter the name of the Server
4. Navigate to **HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server**
5. Change the value of **fDenyTSConnections** from **1** to **0**